# Can you spend access after character creation to improve your character?

Tags: skills, character-advancement, paranoia

I have been looking at the *Paranoia: High Programmers* book, and I am a bit confused about something. At the start of the game, you can use up access to improve your skills.

After creating your character, can you use the access you manage to funnel to your own account in order to improve your character's skills?

Comment: What edition of Paranoia is it, exactly?

Comment: I believe there is only one high programmer book that was published at 2010 and the book doesn't include an edition number.

Comment: @Mołot High Programmers is in the 25th Anniversary Edition line, but as with the other two it is a self-contained system and doesn't need reference to other books for rules. It's got a very different character creation and playstyle to the rest of the Paranoia line.

Comment: As a general rule of thumb in paranoia, if your the gm and you want to allow it and it will make things more fun, allow it, if your players act like they know the rules it’s treason. Maybe let one do it and then when the next tries it overwrites the first, or they can do it but when they get the next clone there is a defect, or they lose the ability or they overwrite themselves and something goes horribly wrong. There are no real rules in paranoia, just a vague set of ideas to keep your players on there toes.

Comment: High programmers have the right to know the rules since they are ultra violet